# How to benchmark methods that throw exceptions?

Tags: jmh

How is one supposed to benchmark methods that throw exceptions using jmh?

I tried the following under jmh 1.19:

```
@Benchmark
public void throwException() throws IllegalArgumentException
{
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hard-coded exception");
}
```

but got this error:

```
# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:02:00
# Fork: 1 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: <failure>

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Hard-coded exception
[...]
```

Am I supposed to blackhole exceptions as follows?

```
@Benchmark
public void throwException(Blackhole bh)
{
    try
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hard-coded exception");
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        bh.consume(e);
    }
}
```

or is there another way to tell `jmh` to accept thrown exceptions?

Comment: Read this https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/ and check this https://github.com/shipilev/article-exception-benchmarks/tree/master/src/main/java/net/shipilev/perf/exceptions

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Okay, but why does it work? What allows his code to throw exceptions whereas mine triggers a failure?

Comment: I think main difference is that example calls a method throwing exception, instead of throwing it from benchmark itself

Comment: @Gili benchmark methods in the JMH examples do not throw exceptions, they catch them and do something in the catch block, that will prevent the compiler from optimizing the throw statement. Blackhole, as in your code, is one way, another is to catch and return the exception object from the benchmark method without using the blackhole explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the answers I've received from I've received from [Kiril S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5318223/kiril-s) and [Oleg Estekhin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541688/oleg-estekhin):

JMH will always fail if a benchmark method throws an exception. To correct this, the benchmark method must catch the exception. It can then consume the exception using a `Blackhole` object, or return it from the benchmark method. This will prevent the compiler from optimizing-away the `throw` statement.